# ZFS: How to find detached disk?

Tags: freebsd, zfs

I had two failed disks in my ZFS pool, which I replaced with hot spares with `zpool replace`. How do I identify the failed disks so I can physically replace them?

Below are outputs of `zpool status` before and after I ran `zpool detach` on the broken disks.

Before `zpool detach`:

```
  pool: mypool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
        continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Tue Jun  7 11:26:56 2016
        123M scanned out of 91,8T at 5,84M/s, (scan is slow, no estimated time)
        5,23M resilvered, 0,00% done
config:

        NAME              STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        myp       DEGRADED     0     0     0
          raidz3-0        ONLINE       0     0     0
            da0           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da1           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da2           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da3           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da16          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da17          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da18          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da19          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da32          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da33          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da34          ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz3-1        ONLINE       0     0     0
            da4           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da5           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da6           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da7           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da20          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da21          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da22          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da23          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da36          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da37          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da38          ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz3-2        DEGRADED     0     0     0
            da8           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da9           ONLINE       0     0     0
            da10          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da11          ONLINE       0     0     0
            spare-4       REMOVED      0     0     0
              2131739493  REMOVED      0     0     0  was /dev/da24
              da35        ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            da25          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da26          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da27          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da41          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da42          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da40          ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz3-3        DEGRADED     0     0     0
            da12          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da13          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da14          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da15          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da28          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da29          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da30          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da31          ONLINE       0     0     0
            spare-8       REMOVED      0     0     0
              1333723008  REMOVED      0     0     0  was /dev/da44
              da39        ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)
            da45          ONLINE       0     0     0
            da46          ONLINE       0     0     0
        logs
          ada3            ONLINE       0     0     0
        cache
          ada2            ONLINE       0     0     0
        spares
          1693614993      INUSE     was /dev/da35
          2127061040      INUSE     was /dev/da39
          da43            AVAIL
          da47            AVAIL

errors: No known data errors
```

After `zpool detach`:

```
  pool: mypool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 66h29m with 0 errors on Mon Jul 25 18:29:18 2016
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    mypool  ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz3-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        da0     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da1     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da2     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da3     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da16    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da17    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da18    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da19    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da32    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da33    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da34    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz3-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        da4     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da5     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da6     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da7     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da20    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da21    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da22    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da23    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da36    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da37    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da38    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz3-2  ONLINE       0     0     0
        da8     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da9     ONLINE       0     0     0
        da10    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da11    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da35    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da25    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da26    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da27    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da41    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da42    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da40    ONLINE       0     0     0
      raidz3-3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        da12    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da13    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da14    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da15    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da28    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da29    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da30    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da31    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da39    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da45    ONLINE       0     0     0
        da46    ONLINE       0     0     0
    logs
      ada3      ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      ada2      ONLINE       0     0     0
    spares
      da43      AVAIL   
      da47      AVAIL   

errors: No known data errors

  pool: zroot
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h1m with 0 errors on Wed Feb 11 10:27:32 2015
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    zroot       ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada0p3  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ada1p3  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

Comment: It's better to move question to unix.stackexchange.com, because stackoverflow is more for programmers, rather than for sysadmins.

Comment: @MichaelZhilin How do I move it?

Comment: afaik, by moderator. I think you can re-publish it on unix site.

Answer (score -1):

You need to identify your controller and enclosure bay. For FreeBSD [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/586838/333167) on serverfault seems to be helpful. If you have LSI SAS controllers, you can then find the enclosure with [sas2ircu](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/sas2ircu/) and the serial number of the disk (and blink the enclosure, if the enclosure supports it).

For the future I would advise to write down disk vendor, type, serial number, enclosure name/number and controller name/port down in a configuration management database (or just on a piece of paper), because it is way faster to not have to look it up, especially with large arrays.

It is also possible on FreeBSD to name your disks with the WWN (world wide name) instead of the numbered da0, da1, ... This means you can see directly which disk has problems and then look them up with simple Ctrl+C/Ctrl+F. Of course you could also script it if you want.